# BinSearch fails after Bubble Sort

Tags: c++, sorting

My program seems to be behaving oddly all of a sudden and I cannot figure out why no matter how I look.

Let's begin with the header

```
    //inventoryData.h
//This is the second edition of inventory data, now featuring an actual description
//This header will load an array, sort it, and then be used in InventorySearch to produce parts and prices.
//by Robert Moore on [DATE]

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class InventoryData{
    //Variables
    private:
        int partNum[1000];
        double price[1000];
        int invCount;

    public:
        InventoryData();//Build Up
        void loadArrays(); //Feed the data from the database into our arrays
        void arraySort(); //Bubblesort for the array
        int seqSearch(int); //Our one by one search method
        int binSearch(int); //The other search
        int returnpart(int); //Return Part Number
        double returnPrice(int); //Return price

        //Incorportate a search counter to both these searches?
                //IE: bin search found [x] (completed after [y] records)

};

InventoryData::InventoryData()
{
    //Load the array
    invCount = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < 1000; count++)
    {
        partNum[count] = 0;
        price[count] = 0;
    }
}

void InventoryData::arraySort()
{
    int counter = 0; //Used to keep track of subscripts
    int temp = 0; //Used to sort subscript contents
    double tempPrice = 0;
    int maxSub = invCount; 
    int lastKnown  = 0; //Used to indicate what the last swapped value was
    char swap = 'Y'; //used to indicate if a swap was made or not

    while (swap == 'Y')
    {
        swap = 'N';
        counter = 0;


        while (counter < maxSub){
            if (partNum[counter] < partNum[counter+1])
            {

                //Swap the part number
                temp = partNum[counter];
                partNum[counter] = partNum[counter+1];
                partNum[counter+1] = temp;

                //Swap the price
                tempPrice = price[counter];
                price[counter] = price[counter+1];
                price[counter+1] = tempPrice;

                //Report the swap occured
                swap = 'Y';
                lastKnown = counter;
            }
            counter++;
            }//End of While Loop
            maxSub = lastKnown;
        }//End this While Loop Too
    cout<<"File sort complete."<<endl;
}

void InventoryData::loadArrays()
    {
        ifstream partIn;
        partIn.open("masterInventory.dat");
        cout<<"Loading..."<<endl;
        if (partIn.is_open())
            {
                //Prime Read
                partIn    >>    partNum[invCount]
                          >>    price[invCount];

                //cout<<partNum[invCount]<<" and "<<price[invCount] <<" have been loaded."<<endl;            

            while(!partIn.eof())
                {
                                invCount++;
                    partIn  >>  partNum[invCount]
                            >>  price[invCount];
            //  cout<<partNum[invCount]<<" and "<<price[invCount] <<" have been loaded."<<endl; 

                } //END While

            partIn.close();
            cout<<"All files loaded successfully."<<endl;
            }   //END IF*/

        else
            {
                invCount = -1;
                cout<<"File failed to open."<<endl;
            }
            //arraySort();
    }



int InventoryData::seqSearch(int searchKey)
{
    int index = 0;
    int found = -1;
    int counter = 0;
    while(index < invCount)
    {
        counter++;
        if (searchKey == partNum[index]
)
        {
            found = index;
            index = invCount;
        }
        else
        {
            index++;
        }

    }
    cout<<"(Sequential completed after reading "<< counter<<" files.)"<<endl;
    return found;

}

int InventoryData::binSearch(int searchKey)
{
    int first = 0;
    int last = invCount;
    int found = 0;
    int mid = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while (first <= last && found == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        mid = (first + last)/2;
        if (searchKey == partNum[mid] ){
            found = 1;

            return mid;
        }
        else
        {
            if (partNum[mid] < searchKey)
            {
                first = mid+1;
            }
            else 
            {
                last = mid - 1;
            }

        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
    {
        mid  = -1;

    }
    cout<<"(Binary completed after reading "<< counter <<" files.)"<<endl;
    return mid;
}

int InventoryData::returnpart(int value)
    {
        return partNum[value];
    }

double InventoryData::returnPrice(int value)
    {
        setprecision(2);
        return price[value];
    }
```

With this set up, the program loads numbers from a database (any random combination of digits and another set of "prices"), then we call the function to load, sort, and search the array, as found in the CPP file

```
//InventorySearch
/*This file is used to search our databases
and return a value for whatever our search may
be looking for.*/
//by Robert Moore


#include "inventoryData.h"
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
    //Declare Variable
    int tempSeq = 0;
    int tempBin = 0;
    int search = 0;
    char confirmation = 'Y';
    int searchCounter = 0;
    int partsFound = 0;
    int partsLost = 0;

    //Build Object and Load Array
    InventoryData invent;
    invent.loadArrays();
    invent.arraySort();

    //Introduction
    cout<<"Welcome to Part Search."<<endl;

//Begin Loop Here
    while(confirmation != 'N')
    {

        cout<<"Please enter a part number: ";
        searchCounter++;
        cin>>search;
        cout<<endl;


        tempSeq = invent.seqSearch(search);
        if (tempSeq != -1)
        {
              std::cout << std::fixed;
            cout<<"Sequential found part number "<<invent.returnpart(tempSeq)<< ", and it's price is "<<setprecision(2)<<invent.returnPrice(tempSeq)<<endl;
            partsFound++;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Sequential search failed to find part number "<<search<<endl;
            partsLost++;
        }

        tempBin = invent.binSearch(search);
    if (tempBin != -1)
        {
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            cout<<"Binary found part number "<<invent.returnpart(tempBin)<<", and it's price is "<<setprecision(2)<<invent.returnPrice(tempBin)<<endl;
            partsFound++;
        }

    else
        {
            cout<<"Binary search failed to find part number "<<search<<endl;
            partsLost++;
        }
        cout<<"Would you like to search again? (Plese enter Y/N): ";
        cin>>confirmation;
        confirmation = toupper(confirmation);
        }

    cout<<"Today's Summary: "<<endl;
    cout<<setw(5)<<"Total searches: "<<setw(25)<<searchCounter<<endl;
    cout<<setw(5)<<"Total successful searches:"<<setw(15)<<(partsFound/2)<<endl;
    cout<<setw(5)<<"Total unsuccessful searches:"<<setw(12)<<(partsLost/2)<<endl;

    cout<<"Thank you for using Part Search. Have a nice day."<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, the output runs into the following problem: where the sequential search will scour the entire database and find our value, the binSearch will only search up to 8 values and fail. At first I thought this was due to the way the sort was loaded, but once I coded it out, it continued to fail. Worse yet, aside from adding the sort, the program function just fine prior to this.

I'm running out of ideas as to where the program is wrong, as this code worked just fine up until arraySort() was added.

Answer (score 1):

In your `arraySort()` method, you should take note of the fact that for instance if `maxSub=10`, then for the part where you write

```
 while (counter < maxSub){
        if (partNum[counter] < partNum[counter+1])
        {
         .....
        }
 }
```

you might end up performing

```
 if(partNum[9]<partNum[10]){
  ....
 }
```

Since C++ does not perform bound checking on arrays, your code, although buggy, might end up compiling successfully, and may (or may not) produce the correct result. Thus you need to change the loop condition to

```
  while((counter+1)<maxSub){
     .....
  }
```

Besides, your `arraySort()` is sorting in the Descending order, and your `binSearch()` has been implemented for an array sorted in ascending order. You can change either of the methods as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your sorting algorithm seems faulty to me. If you are trying bubble sort, sorting implementation should be like this.

```
for(int counter1 = 0;counter1<invCount; ++counter1)
{
    for(int counter2 = counter1+1; counter2<invCount; ++counter2)
    {
        if(partNum[counter1] < partNum[counter2])
        {
             //do swaping here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not bubblesort; its a *nearly* correct selection-sort.